# creating formula in MS excel sheet to fetch value from row and column

Tags: excel

I have a sheet that contains some data. every day we have to fetch values from it.
[C3] [D3] [I1] is example of format we receive to fetch data. characters are columns and numbers are rows and so we have to match the required value manually and provide output.
Can yo help me create formula so that I can paste " [C1] [B3] [E2]" - this format in a cell and receive the output in any other cell. 
 I have attached a snap for the reference

[Snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFhV7.jpg)

Comment: So you want the values of those three cells in one cell or three different cells?  If one how do you want it delineated? With commas, spaces or something else?

Comment: thank you for replying. i want output in one cell and with out any comma or space.

Comment: Next round of questions: is it always three cell references or is that variable?

Comment: ya that is constant, there will be 3 cell reference always. i have also attached a snap for reference .. i may give you better understanding for my question.

Comment: Did any of the two answers help?  If so please mark one as correct.  Only you can do it.  It is the only way to close the question.  Click on the green check mark by the correct answer, the one you used.

Answer (score 1):

The following formulas use `FIND` to look for the relative positions of each square bracket in the reference cell, you can then use `LEFT` and `RIGHT` to return the contents of each square bracket pair. Finally it uses `INDIRECT` to make Excel read the text string as a cell reference.

`=INDIRECT(LEFT(RIGHT(H1,LEN(H1)-FIND("[",H1)),FIND("]",H1)-FIND("[",H1)-1))`

`=INDIRECT(LEFT(RIGHT(H1,LEN(H1)-FIND("[",H1,FIND("]",H1))),FIND("]",H1,FIND("[",H1,FIND("]",H1)))-FIND("[",H1,FIND("]",H1))-1))`

`=INDIRECT(LEFT(RIGHT(H1,LEN(H1)-FIND("[",H1,FIND("]",H1,FIND("[",H1,FIND("]",H1))))),FIND("]",H1,FIND("[",H1,FIND("]",H1,FIND("[",H1,FIND("]",H1)))))-FIND("[",H1,FIND("]",H1,FIND("[",H1,FIND("]",H1))))-1))`

You can concatenate the results into one cell using the `&` sign, like this:

`=INDIRECT(LEFT(RIGHT(H1,LEN(H1)-FIND("[",H1)),FIND("]",H1)-FIND("[",H1)-1))&INDIRECT(LEFT(RIGHT(H1,LEN(H1)-FIND("[",H1,FIND("]",H1))),FIND("]",H1,FIND("[",H1,FIND("]",H1)))-FIND("[",H1,FIND("]",H1))-1))&INDIRECT(LEFT(RIGHT(H1,LEN(H1)-FIND("[",H1,FIND("]",H1,FIND("[",H1,FIND("]",H1))))),FIND("]",H1,FIND("[",H1,FIND("]",H1,FIND("[",H1,FIND("]",H1)))))-FIND("[",H1,FIND("]",H1,FIND("[",H1,FIND("]",H1))))-1))`

**EDIT:**

It might be easier to visualize what Excel is doing with `SUBSTITUTE` instead, in which you are able to specify which *instance* of a particular character you want to focus on. In the formula below, we substitute a particular left and right square bracket with the tilde sign for our `FIND` formula to look for, and then reference the substring between the two.

`=MID(H1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(H1,"[","~",1))+1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(H1,"]","~",1))-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(H1,"[","~",1))-1)`

That way, to find the second, third, *n*th cell reference, we just increment the instance number:

`=MID(H1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(H1,"[","~",2))+1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(H1,"]","~",2))-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(H1,"[","~",2))-1)`

`=MID(H1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(H1,"[","~",3))+1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(H1,"]","~",3))-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(H1,"[","~",3))-1)`

Again, you would wrap each of these in `INDIRECT` and then concatenate with `&`:

`=INDIRECT(MID(H1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(H1,"[","~",1))+1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(H1,"]","~",1))-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(H1,"[","~",1))-1))&INDIRECT(MID(H1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(H1,"[","~",2))+1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(H1,"]","~",2))-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(H1,"[","~",2))-1))&INDIRECT(MID(H1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(H1,"[","~",3))+1,FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(H1,"]","~",3))-FIND("~",SUBSTITUTE(H1,"[","~",3))-1))`

It isn't any shorter than the first formula (for now), but it's perhaps easier to understand the logic. More importantly, it's a lot easier to extend this version to include additional cell references, for example if H1 contained "[A1] [B12] [D32] [E4] [F19]" you just concatenate a couple more copies of the whole `INDIRECT` formula and increment the instance number for each one.

Comment: For taking the time to actually write this long formula. (+1)

Comment: FWIW you will need to wrap your whole thing in `()` before the `--`, or it will only apply the `--` to the first part.  I was trying to find a shorter version but could not so I went with the UDF

Answer (score 1):

If vba works for you then this quick UDF will do it:

```
Function CONCATENATESPECIAL(rng As Range) As string
    Dim spArr() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim temp As String
    temp = Replace(rng, "[", "")
    temp = Replace(temp, "]", "")
    spArr = Split(temp)
    For i = LBound(spArr) To UBound(spArr)
        CONCATENATESPECIAL = CONCATENATESPECIAL & Range(spArr(i))
    Next i
End Function
```

Put this in a module attached to the workbook:

[image]

Then you would simply use it as any other formula:

```
=CONCATENATESPECIAL(H1)
```

This will return a string.  If you want to turn it into a number then:

```
=--CONCATENATESPECIAL(H1)
```

Comment: Very concise, and this has the added benefit of handling *any* number of `[]` delimited cell references. Definitely the preferable solution if you are able to go with the *.xslm format. Also, good catch with the string output. Same thing happens with mine, so it too would need the `--` prefix to convert to numeric.